# How to restrict visibility of items?

Tags: javafx-2, visibility, pane

Imagine that we have an `AnchorPane`, it has child `Pane` and there we have `Button`, for example.
I want this `Button` to be shown only inside this `Pane`.
In other words, it whould be cut by the `Pane` edges if it is not completely within `Pane`. Now the `Button` can be visible even if it is out of `Pane` rectangle.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

this is what the [clip](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#clipProperty) of a node is made for.

Example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class ClipTest extends Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    Group root = new Group();

    StackPane pane = new StackPane();

    pane.setMaxWidth(100);
    pane.setMaxHeight(100);
    pane.setLayoutX(50);
    pane.setLayoutY(50);


    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(100, 100);

    rect.setFill(null);
    rect.setStroke(Color.RED);

    Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(150, 150);

    rect2.setFill(Color.BLUE);

    pane.getChildren().addAll(rect2, rect);

    root.getChildren().add(pane);


//    Rectangle clip = new Rectangle(100, 100);
//    clip.setLayoutX(25);
//    clip.setLayoutY(25);
//    pane.setClip(clip);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 250, 250);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
  }
}
```

This produces:

[image: without clip]

Uncommenting the lines regarding the clip produces:

[image: with clip]

Comment: Example could be more simple

Comment: @jeppla ha, really? What kind of high level complaint is that?

Answer (score 6):

You can use [clipping](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setClip%28javafx.scene.Node%29) functionality to achieve this.

```
public class ClipPane extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Pane clipPane = new Pane();
        clipPane.setStyle("-fx-border-color: red;");
        clipPane.setPrefSize(200, 200);

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(200, 200);
        clipPane.setClip(rect);

        Button btn = new Button("Hello, world!");
        btn.relocate(120, 0);
        clipPane.getChildren().add(btn);

        AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();
        root.getChildren().add(clipPane);
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(clipPane, 50.);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(clipPane, 50.);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 300));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(); }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Another approach, with using of observables. To clip items outside pane bounds (like css oveflow:hidden):

```
// create rectangle with sizes of pane, 
// dont need to set x and y explictly 
// as positions of clip node are relative to parent node 
// (to pane in our case)
Rectangle clipRect = new Rectangle(pane.getWidth(), pane.getHeight());

// bind properties so height and width of rect 
// changes according pane's width and height
clipRect.heightProperty().bind(pane.heightProperty());
clipRect.widthProperty().bind(pane.widthProperty());

// set rect as clip rect
pane.setClip(clipRect);
```

Comment: This is great, though... Initial size of clip seems to be ignored. Is there a way to modify this in any way to preserve the label border?